# npm install failed for a package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying to install a package giving errors described here:
Setup is new, everything working, just that the package in question has dependency  mentioned as node-sass: ^5. Compatibility chart shows node 16 is compatible with node-sass 6.0+. Not sure what is the issue. Here is part of log.

```
#] npm install --save react-timeline-range-slider


npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/src -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/config -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/uv/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/zlib -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c
npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/src -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/config -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/uv/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/zlib -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c
npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/src -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/config -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/uv/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/zlib -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c
npm ERR!   g++ -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/src -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/config -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/uv/include -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/zlib -I/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c
.. .. ..

npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c: In function ‘base64_encode_block’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:48:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    48 |    result = (fragment & 0x003) << 4;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:52:2: note: here
npm ERR!    52 |  case step_B:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:62:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    62 |    result = (fragment & 0x00f) << 2;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:66:2: note: here
npm ERR!    66 |  case step_C:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp: In function ‘void Sass::Functions::handle_utf8_error(const Sass::ParserState&, Sass::Backtraces)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:110:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_code_point’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   110 |       catch (utf8::invalid_code_point) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:114:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::not_enough_room’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   114 |       catch (utf8::not_enough_room) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:118:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_utf8’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   118 |       catch (utf8::invalid_utf8) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_encode_string(const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:405:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   405 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_stringify(const JsonNode*, const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:424:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   424 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8.h:30,
npm ERR!                  from /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/node.h:63,
npm ERR!                  from ../../../../nan/nan.h:60,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                  ^
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                               ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../../../nan/nan.h:60,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/node.h:847:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   847 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/node.h:881:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!   881 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
npm ERR!       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-121-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/REACT/apps/Operational/sp-17-afs/node_modules/react-timeline-range-slider/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2022-07-18T11_27_12_527Z-debug-0.log
```

Version Info:
Node -v v16.15.1
React 7

I am not sure about the error, rechecked NODE in $PATH, tried installing node-sass first, similar kind of errors. Any hints?

Comment: There is a known issue with `node-sass`, they say you have to move to `dart-sass`, see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Seems to be an open issue about it: https://github.com/lizashkod/react-timeline-range-slider/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

npm WARN deprecated `tar@2.2.2`: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.  to fix  this issue run this command : `npm i tar`

then :

```
npm install --save react-timeline-range-slider
```

Comment: thats okay, and its warning only... More concerned about why build getting failed.